# ssh connect and commands programmatically

Tags: bash, ssh, command

I'm trying to make a script connecting via an SSH connection to a server and executing some commands. The first part works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh address
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

but after that I want to execute some more commands, e.g `cd` to directory, launch some more scripts etc. Is there any way to implement these things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set login "any_user"
set addr "some_address"
set pw "any_pwd"

spawn ssh -t $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "~" ; # put here string from your server prompt
send "mkdir some_dir\r"
interact
```

This is one of the command, you could try other commands like cd, any other scripts too in it and let us know if any queries.

Comment: yes, this works, 
thanks a lot!
As I understand, I need to set expect command each time  I want to send anything

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easier approaches than using `spawn`, `expect`, `interact`, etc.:

1. The easiest approach is to execute a command with `ssh`. For example listing directories of your remote with `ls`:

```bash
# Either enter the password in a prompt...
ssh ssh-username@123.4.5.67 ls

# ...or use sshpass to avoid the password prompt
SSHPASS='XXXXX' sshpass -e ssh ssh-username@123.4.5.67 ls
```

2. Create a SSH tunnel. There are a lot of tutorials in the web on how to do this in different ways.